# Is there a Discrete version of the Normal Distribution?

Tags: probability

- Suppose I have a Normal Distribution with $\mu = 50$ and $\sigma^2 = 15$.
- If I "force" this Normal Distribution to only take values between the integers 0 to 100 ....  I can find out the probability of this specific Normal Distribution taking values between the intervals (0,1), (1,2), (2,3) ... (98,99), (99,100)
- Informally, I could then make this into a Multinomial Probability Distribution with the same number of outcomes as intervals, alongside the corresponding probabilities of landing into any one of these given intervals

**My Question:** Is there a more formal mathematical way to do this? Can the Normal Distribution be transformed into some Discrete Distribution?

In a similar sense, given a Normal Distribution, a range of values, a number of $k$ bins (i.e. intervals), and the position/width for each of these $k$ bins : is there a more mathematical way that a Normal Distribution can be transformed into a similar looking Discrete Distribution (e.g. Multinomial Distribution)?

Thanks!

**References:**

- [discrete version of normal distribution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3138663/discrete-version-of-normal-distribution)
- [Discretized normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219417/discretized-normal-distribution)
- [Is there something like a normal distribution model for discrete probability?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1908754/is-there-something-like-a-normal-distribution-model-for-discrete-probability)
- [Finite discrete approximation to the normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920252/finite-discrete-approximation-to-the-normal-distribution)
- [Approximating a discrete probability distribution with a standard normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2823370/approximating-a-discrete-probability-distribution-with-a-standard-normal-distrib)
- [What is the closest equivalent to a Gaussian distribution on a discrete domain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3936929/what-is-the-closest-equivalent-to-a-gaussian-distribution-on-a-discrete-domain)
- [Can a discrete random variable be normally distributed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4126458/can-a-discrete-random-variable-be-normally-distributed)

Comment: [Discrete Gaussian distributions via theta functions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.02373.pdf) ?

Comment: @ r.e.s. : thank you for your reply! this link you posted looks quite complicated and is beyond my level of understanding :( I was hoping perhaps there was some "standard/popular" type of distribution I could use (e.g. multinomial).